# Drupal URL change, rewrite goes to static

Tags: .htaccess, drupal

Setup on media temple, second domain name, same server.

Website duplicated from domainA.com, to domainB.com, under the vhosts. Changed drupal's settings.php to reflect the new domain. When checking under the admin settings, the default front page is listed under the domainB.com URL. So that checks out okay.

Navigate to domainB.com and it resolves as domainA.com's name.

Both domainA & domainB are loading from domainB's folder. This assumption is made because I only changed settings.php in domainB, not domainA, and they are both displaying the data for domainB.

The issue is the address bar is displaying domainA's name.

domainB's htaccess file has:

```
# enforce https
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domainB.com/$1 [R,L]

# redirect www
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domainB\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domainB.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# drupal subdirectory
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ drupal/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^$ drupal/ [L]

# disallow indexes
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks

php_flag log_errors on
php_value error_reporting 32767
php_value error_log "/var/www/vhosts/domainB.com/logs/php_error.log"
```

Goals:
1) domainB is identical in operation to domainA, except for domainB's name displaying in the navigation bar and internal links.
2) domainA points to a static page.

Comment: Does your website use specific language settings? Sometimes when you use multi lingual settings you have to fill out on your Settings > Language -> <some language> -> Edit
There you fix your domain name. It can be interfering with your config.

Comment: I'm guessing that you've resolved this issue? but if not, could you post the relevant vhost files?